# How to browse other Xubuntu installation files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, xubuntu

my hard disk has two `xubuntu 9.04` installation.

one installation in partition `/dev/sda1`

and another installation in partition `/dev/sda5`

if I running xubuntu installation in partition `/dev/sda5`, how to browse other Xubuntu installation files in partition `/dev/sda1`?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make files in `/dev/sda1` accessible under the running operating system. The underlying operation is called [mounting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/what-is-meant-by-mounting-a-device-in-linux). I think under default Ubuntu settings there will be an entry for `/dev/sda1` in the “Places” menu; I don't know how that translates to the Xubuntu interface.

To mount your other installation manually, you can use the following command:

```
sudo mkdir /media/sda1
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1
```

The files from `/dev/sda1` will now be available under `/media/sda1`. When you've finished browsing:

```
sudo umount /media/sda1
sudo rmdir /media/sda1
```

You don't need the `rmdir` part unless you want to completely clean up after yourself. And the `umount` will happen automatically when you shut down your computer.

If you'd like to have `/dev/sda1` permanently accessible, add an entry corresponding to it in `/etc/fstab`, which contains information about filesystems to mount at boot time.

```
sudoedit /etc/fstab
```

Add the following line near the bottom of the file:

```
/dev/sda1  /media/sda1  auto  auto
```

---

You may be interested in the `chroot` command. It lets you run a program pretending to restrict the filesystem to a subtree. For example, if you run

```
sudo chroot /media/sda1 bash
```

you will get a shell where it appears that only the files from `/dev/sda1` exist. This shell will run as root; you can use `su` to switch to a user that exists inside the other installation. Some commands may not run in this environment, complaining about a missing `proc`; you can satisfy them by running (as root, inside the chroot)

```
mount -t proc proc /proc
```

Running GUI applications inside the chroot is possible but the setup is a little complicated.